# What is the purpose of the roles: 'HTTPDestAdministrator' and HTTPDestAdministrator?

Tags: hana

From the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/9f/dfbe396db9496c993779db91df01aa/content.htm?frameset=/en/68/6f32f2da7947368f8a6906860bc19b/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/00/0ca1e3486640ef8b884cdf1a050fbb/plain.htm&node_id=718), I can understand that when assigning users these particular roles, the user has specific priveleges:

HTTPDestAdministrator:  Full access to the details of HTTP destination configurations (display and edit)

HTTPDestViewer: Read-only access to HTTP destination configurations, which are used to specify connection details for outbound connections, for example, using the server-side JavaScript Connectivity API that is included with SAP HANA XS.

This is a little verbose and hard to conceptualize when it is needed in an application development. Can someone please expand on these definitions?

EDIT: I'm familiar with HTTP protocol, but what is the 'destination' configured to? Path to the HANA DB? External sources? Clientside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has little to do with the database side of the house. These settings are for XS JavaScript applications running 'on top' of the database. 
Let's say you want to use a specific external HTTP service in your application, say the Yahoo Weather or Finance information supply, then you have to setup this connection as an HTTP destination.
The SAP HANA documentation covers that in quite some detail: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/80/13b1b9beb14bdabacbea6e4d7c4bb3/content.htm?frameset=/en/ca/340c09551c40b7837e773b9d051821/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/6e/284b62132c41caa173bf590e9be084/plain.htm&node_id=47

Comment: Thank you, that's a little bit clearer now. Just to confirm, when you mention that its purpose is to 'use a specific external HTTP service in your application" (like Yahoo Finance or Weather), the HTTP service is the API hub for yahoo finance/weather (example) that our app would now have access to? I'm still trying to iron out what exactly the HTTP service is since 'service' is a common term. Is it anything that uses the HTTP Protocol?

Comment: The HANA XS JavaScript environment comes with an API that allows to call external HTTP services (practically everything that you can call via http url and retrieve the result in the response). "The SAP HANA Developer Guide - For SAP HANA Web Workbench" has a whole example tutorial for that. 
Bottomline of that idea is that all external data accesses get channelled through the API and the list of defined destinations That should make controlling such access easier.